# FOSUserBundle - Registration controller override error

Tags: symfony, controller, fosuserbundle

I am trying to override the registration controller of FOSUserBundle.
Here's my configuration :

```
services:
    project.registration.controller:
        class: Project\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController
        arguments: [ @event_dispatcher,@fos_user.registration.form.factory,@fos_user.user_manager,@security.token_storage]
```

And the controller so far:

```
<?php
namespace Project\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController as BaseController;

class RegistrationController extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct(EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher, FactoryInterface $formFactory, UserManagerInterface $userManager, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        parent::__construct($eventDispatcher, $formFactory, $userManager, $tokenStorage);
    }
```

However everytime i try to go to the registration page I meet this error :

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Project\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface, none given, called in C:\wamp\www\cmagic\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver.php on line 187 and defined
```

I think I followed for controllers used as services or did I miss a step ?

**EDIT :** This is for symfony 2.8

Comment: What is it that you are wanting to override in the controller? To be honest those controller do pretty much everything required and dispatch events that 90% of the time you can just hook a few event listeners and handle things that way.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me in Symfony 3, but getParent(){} for bundles is already deprecated in 3.4 version and disabled in 4.

```
namespace AppBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

---

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;



use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController as BaseController;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class RegistrationController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
        /** @var $formFactory FactoryInterface */
        $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.registration.form.factory');
        /** @var $userManager UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        /** @var $dispatcher EventDispatcherInterface */
        $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');

        $user = $userManager->createUser();
        $user->setEnabled(true);

        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);

        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
            return $event->getResponse();
        }

        $form = $formFactory->createForm();
        $form->setData($user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
                $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

                $userManager->updateUser($user);

                if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                    $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
                    $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
                }

                $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

                return $response;
            }

            $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_FAILURE, $event);

            if (null !== $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                return $response;
            }
        }

        return $this->render('@FOSUser/Registration/register.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: That was what I did first and I  got the same error not on my controller but on the FOSUserBundle RegistrationController.

Comment: It is strange, beacuse the fos user controller does not have a __construct method at all, it gets eventDispatcher from container in register action `/** @var $dispatcher EventDispatcherInterface */
        $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');`

Comment: oh, i got it, try to use more recent version of FOSUserBundle , i am using this one `"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",`

Comment: The Bundle is now up to date  on 2.1.2 , I still got this error.

Comment: Can you try to use my registerAction method that i provided above without counstructor and without service  configuration.

Comment: I found the cause : the problem is with UserBundle version 2.1, I rolled back to 2.0.2 and it works now.